# How to install DR14 T.meter on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: dependencies, 19.10

- Where to find an official deb package?
- How to satisfy dependencies?

DR14 T.meter is a free and open-source command-line tool for computing the Dynamic Range of your music according to the procedure used in the off-line meter released by the Pleasurize Music Foundation.

This tool is handy to measure how is loud your music and for understanding that a good quality album always has also a good dynamic, and it's also useful for understanding the effects of the so-called [loudness war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loudness_war).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Official Resources**

[DR14 T.meter Official Web Page](http://dr14tmeter.sourceforge.net/index.php/DR14_T.meter)
[DR14 T.meter Official DEB Package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/python-support_1.0.15_all.deb) (current version 1.0.15)
[DR14 T.meter source on GitHub](https://github.com/simon-r/dr14_t.meter)

---

**Install on Ubuntu 19.10**

```
# Dependencies from Ubuntu Repositories
sudo apt install lame flac vorbis-tools faad dh-python python-scipy python-numpy

# DR14 T.medter can draw spectrograms and other graphs using python-matplotlib
# If you plan to use this (really not sexy results) feature, the package will be required
# Optionnal :
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib

# python-support is required, not available on Ubuntu repos
# but can be found on the Ubuntu Launchpad
wget "https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/python-support_1.0.15_all.deb"
sudo dpkg -i python-support_1.0.15_all.deb

# Now lets DL and Install dr14tmeter
wget "https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/dr14tmeter/dr14tmeter-1.0.16/dr14tmeter_1.0.16-1_all.deb"
sudo dpkg -i dr14tmeter_1.0.16-1_all.deb

# Downloaded deb files can be deleted
# rm dr14tmeter_1.0.16-1_all.deb python-support_1.0.15_all.deb
```

---

**Better option : PIP install**

With python 3 and pip 3

```
# use 'pip -V' and 'whereis pip' to select pip python 3.x version

sudo -H pip install numpy scipy
sudo -H pip install DR14-T.meter
```

---

**Usage**

```
# Basic
cd ~/Music/An/Album
dr14_tmeter ./

# Compute multiple folders, sort result
cd ~/Music/An/Artist
find * -maxdepth 0 ! -path . -type d -exec dr14_tmeter -a -t t -o ./ {} \;
```